# Report where id

Tags: php, codeigniter, fpdf

I'm having trouble printing data based on ID,
error :

> Too few arguments to function M_order::cetak_db_order(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs.......\Order.php on line 162 and exactly 1 expected

**submit id**

```
<td class="text-center"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>backend/order/cetak_order/<?php echo $m->id_service; ?>" class="btn bg-navy btn-flat margin">Detail order</a></td>
```

**Model code**

```
 public function cetak_db_order($id){
    $hasil=$this->db->query("
        SELECT id_service,kd_cs,nama_cs,reciver_name,tanggal,status,nama_kecamatan AS tujuan, nama_kabupaten AS asal 
        FROM service s
        INNER JOIN customers c ON s.id_cs=c.id_cs 
        INNER JOIN kabupaten k ON s.id_origin=k.id_kab 
        INNER JOIN kecamatan p ON p.id_kec=s.id_destination WHERE id_service='$id'");
    return $hasil->result();
}
```

**Controller code**

```
public function cetak_order(){
    $pdf = new FPDF('l','mm','A5');
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
    $pdf->Cell(20,6,'Nama',1,0);
    $pdf->Cell(85,6,'penerima',1,0);
    $pdf->Cell(27,6,'asal',1,0);
    $pdf->Cell(25,6,'tujuan',1,1);
    $cetakorder = $this->M_order->cetak_db_order();
    foreach ($cetakorder as $row){
        $pdf->Cell(20,6,$row->nama_cs,1,0);
        $pdf->Cell(85,6,$row->reciver_name,1,0);
        $pdf->Cell(27,6,$row->asal,1,0);
        $pdf->Cell(25,6,$row->tujuan,1,1); 
    }
    $pdf->Output();
}
```

Comment: try `table.id_service`

Comment: not work :( @devsi odedra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `$m->id_service` from the anchor Tag in HTML. But you are not using it anywhere in the PHP.

You need to update your `cetak_order` function like below:

```
public function cetak_order( $id ){
.
.
.
.
.
$cetakorder = $this->M_order->cetak_db_order( $id );
```

Also you need to make sure to pass `$id` to `cetak_order` method from wherever you are calling it, unless it is passed automatically by your router.